# PHP SimpleXML - Node as string

Tags: php, casting, simplexml

Im trying to get a XML node (with children) as string but had no success.

Here my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
  <main_settings>
    <id>23</account_id>
    <test/>
    <logo_url/>
    <app appid="test_12">
      <d:tag xmlns:c="http://mypage.com/test2" id="mypage_id_256" type="mypage_type_test">
        <path-info value="show"/>
      </d:tag>
    </app>
  </main_settings>
</params>
```

This is not working.

```
    $var->params->main_settings->app;
```

Is there a way to get with simpleXML a nodes ("app") childs as sting?

Comment: What are you trying to get as your text in that example?  `test_12`?

Comment: No. i need the node d:tag tag as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [asXml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method on the child:

```
$var->params->main_settings->app->asXml();
```

It's also possible via typecasting:

```
(string)$var->params->main_settings->app
```

Comment: I tried this. But the childrens are not in the string. Just the node "d:tag".

Comment: Could you post your output and code? I'm not sure if we're talking about the same, because d:tag IS a children of app.

Comment: Im sure, we are talking about the same issue. My problem is, that i cannot write the complete node in html. Firefox just shows mothertag. The children are not included. With htmlspecialchars i can see it completly

Comment: Can you see the children when you display the source code in Firefox?

Comment: I can see "d:tag" in by using $xml->asXML(); Bu i need only "d:tag" as string. I dont mean the contents in "d:tag". I need the full node as String "<d:tag ....... </d:tag>"

Comment: OK. I solved it now with "$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);"  and "$xml->main_settings->app->children($ns['d'])->asXML();"